# Does a pair of complex embeddings correspond to a single complex prime?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, valuation-theory

I'm reading through Neukirch's Algebraic Number Theory, and he distinguishes between a number field's real primes, given by its real embeddings, and its complex primes, which are induced by the pairs of complex conjugate non-real embeddings. What I'm confused about is whether the pair of complex embeddings is a *single* complex prime, or does the pair of complex embeddings correspond to a *pair* of complex primes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neukirch defines a prime as a class of equivalent valuations [(1.1), page 184].  A pair of complex conjugate embeddings lead to equivalent valuations, and thus represent a single prime. This is clear, since if $\tau$  and $\overline{\tau}$ are the embeddings, then the corresponding valuations $|\tau(x)|$ and $|\overline{\tau}(x)|$ are identical.